# Is it permitted for a gentile to say jewish prayers?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, gentiles

The title pretty much says it all. Is it permitted for a gentile to say jewish prayers to Hashem ?

How about a gentile who is on the path to conversion ? Would he be permitted to say jewish prayers ?

Answer (score 0):

A great resource for questions on prayer for gentiles, and the Seven Laws, is this:
https://asknoah.org/forum/forumdisplay.php?fid=5

There's an entire booklet dedicated to prayer for Noahides written by Rabbi Moshe Weiner. And a portion of it is written in his great work The Divine Code. 
https://asknoah.org

** I found the exact question you ask here:
https://asknoah.org/forum/showthread.php?tid=25